# Is $f(x)\oplus x$ a one-way function?

Tags: one-way-function

Given that $f$ is a OWF and $|f(x)|=|x|$ for all $x$, is $g(x)=f(x)\oplus x$ necessarily also a OWF?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While poncho's answer gives an interesting example, why this can go wrong in practice, it does not necessarily answer the question from a theoretical point of view.
After all, we don't **know** whether $f(x) = AES_k(x) \oplus x$ is one-way. (Even if it might be reasonable to assume that.)

So, let's give a theoretical example.
Assume that a one-way function $h$ exists where in- and output length are the same. We call this length $n/2$. I.e. we have a one-way function $$h : \{0,1\}^{n/2} \to \{0,1\}^{n/2}.$$

From this function, we now construct a new function 
$$f : \{0,1\}^{n} \to \{0,1\}^{n}$$ as follows:
$$f(x_1\Vert x_2) = 0^{n/2}\Vert h(x_1),$$
where $|x_1|=|x_2|=n/2$.

It is easy to show via reduction that $f$ is one-way whenever $h$ is one-way.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an attacker against the one-wayness of $f$, then we construct an attacker $\mathcal{B}$ against the one-wayness of $h$ as follows:
Upon input of $y$, $\mathcal{B}$ invokes $\mathcal{A}$ on input $0^{n/2}\Vert y$. Eventually, $\mathcal{A}$ outputs $x_1'\Vert x_2'$ and $\mathcal{B}$ outputs $x_1'$.

It is trivial to see that if $\mathcal{A}$ runs in polynomial time (in input length $n$) then $\mathcal{B}$ also runs in polynomial time (in input length $n/2$).

It is also easy to see the following holds: $$\Pr[\mathcal{B}(y) \in h^{-1}(y)] = \Pr[\mathcal{A}(0^{n/2}\Vert y) \in f^{-1}(0^{n/2}\Vert y)].$$
Therefore it follows that $f$ is one-way whenever $h$ is.

Now lets use this function $f$ in the proposed construction:

$$g(x) = f(x)\oplus x = (0^{n/2}\Vert h(x_1) ) \oplus x_1\Vert x_2 = x_1\Vert (h(x_1)\oplus x_2)$$

This is obviously not one-way. An attacker upon seeing an image $x_1\Vert y$ can simply output $x_1\Vert (y\oplus h(x_1))$ as a valid preimage.

Comment: I think $x_{\hspace{.02 in}1}$ should be replaced with $x_{\hspace{.02 in}1}'$. $\:$ Also, one can let the construction have slightly better $\hspace{.4 in}$ efficiency in general by letting $\hspace{.04 in}f$'s input and output lengths be $m$ and $n$ instead of $n/2$ and $n/2$. $\hspace{.64 in}$

Comment: Thanks, fixed the $x_1$ mixup. About the generality, yes that is true, as long as the length of $x_1$ is superlogarithmic, everything should be fine. But as this is a counter example, I think it's fine to be more specific.

Comment: Of course, this is only a counter-example if one-way functions exist at all.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann If one-way functions don't exist then the question is vacuous since it is predicated on $f$ being a one-way function :)

Comment: If one-way functions do not exist, then the statement is trivially true, because it is an all quantified statement about the empty set.

Comment: @Maeher : $\:$ To make do with merely superlogarithmic-length $x_{\hspace{.02 in}1}$ (or even polylogarithmic-length), one would need $\hspace{.02 in}f$ be be secure against [SUBEXP](http://cse.unl.edu/~cbourke/latex/ComplexityZoo.pdf)-time adversaries. $\;$

Comment: Just FYI, I borrowed your construction for [a (community wiki) answer to a related question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24348/composing-two-one-way-functions-such-that-the-result-is-not-a-one-way-function/24351#24351).

Answer (score 7):

No, you can find $f$ such that $f(x)$ is a OWF, but $f(x)\oplus x$ is not.

One example would be $f(x) = AES_k(x) \oplus x$ (for a public key $k$, perhaps the all-zeros key).  $f(x)$ is believed to be one way; as there is no known practical way, given a value $y$, to find an $x$ with $f(x) = y$.  However, $g(x) = f(x) \oplus x = AES_k(x)$ is easy to invert (because we know the AES key $k$).