# Composing two one-way functions such that the result is not a one-way function

Tags: one-way-function

Is it possible to have two distinct one-way functions (called, say, $h$ and $g$) such that their composition $h \circ g = [\, x \mapsto h(g(x)) \,]$ is not one-way?

Comment: You mean "two", right?

Comment: if this was possible, wouldn't the one way function be broken since it's not ONE WAY. also isn't this kind of Asymmetric cryptography?

Comment: There are many properties of a one-way function. Can you break any with the composition to satisfy the requirements, or is there a specific property (e.g., one-wayness) that must be broken?

Comment: BTW, see [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7076)

Comment: @ebad Is traditional function composition (introduced in Ilmari's edit) what you were looking for or can the composition operation be something different?

Comment: dear mikeazo suppose we have two functions such as $h$ and  $g$ with tow condtions.$\new$ first : they have to be one-way and the second :they have to be distinct $\\$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function $f$ introduced by [Maeher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/975/maeher) in [this answer to a related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22804/is-fx-oplus-x-a-one-way-function/22825#22825) should also do the job here (as both $g$ and $h$).  For convenience, let me quote that answer here:

> Assume that a one-way function $h$ exists where in- and output length are the same. We call this length $n/2$. I.e. we have a one-way function $$h : \{0,1\}^{n/2} \to \{0,1\}^{n/2}.$$
>
> From this function, we now construct a new function
> $$f : \{0,1\}^{n} \to \{0,1\}^{n}$$ as follows:
> $$f(x_1\Vert x_2) = 0^{n/2}\Vert h(x_1),$$
> where $|x_1|=|x_2|=n/2$.

As shown in Maeher's answer, $f$ is one-way if $h$ is.  However, $f(f(x)) = 0^{n/2}\Vert h(0^{n/2})$ is *constant*, independently of $x$ (except for its length $n$), and thus finding pre-images is trivial.

Comment: Ps. If you really must have two *distinct* one-way functions, you could always, say, use $1^{n/2}$ instead of $0^{n/2}$ for one of them.

Answer (score -2):

Ilmari's answer is incorrect.

$f(f(x))$ is not equal to $0^{n/2}\| h(0^{n/2})$. Instead it equals $0^{n/2}\| h(h(x))$ which is not necessarily easy to invert. In particular, if $h \circ h$ is also one-way then $f \circ f$ would also be one way.

Comment: Sorry, the answer is actually correct since $h$ is applied to $x_1$ and not $x_2$. My bad.

Comment: If this answer is incorrect I would remove or rewrite it. The normal way of disapproving is to downvote. But I admire your guts, I would not trust myself to go against Ilmari when it comes to equations ;)