# Composition of an injective/surjective function and a one-way function remains a one-way function?

Tags: one-way-function

I recently read about OWFs and realized that the composition of two OWFs (called, say, $g$ and $f$) are not necessarily an OWF. However, if I modify the question a little bit and fix $g$ to be an injective function, with $f$ still being an OWF, is their composition $g(f(x))$ a one-way function?

I now understand the intuition, thanks to the comments.

If $g$ is no longer one-to-one, can we prove that the composition of $g$ and $f$ is not always a one-way function in the same way as to how we proved that $f2(x)$ is not an OWF [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24348/composing-two-one-way-functions-such-that-the-result-is-not-a-one-way-function)?

Comment: If you are using an injective function on the output, you're essentially just "renaming" the output values.

Comment: and, note that an injective function doesn't need to be surjective.

Comment: @SEJPM If g is efficiently computable, then you are right.

Comment: This problem has been solved in the comments, if any other question pop ups then please ask a separate question, otherwise it may go unnoticed.