# Is a mapping of a k bit string to another k bit string containing 1's a one way function?

Tags: one-way-function

I'm new to cryptanalysis and I saw in another answer to a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24348/composing-two-one-way-functions-such-that-the-result-is-not-a-one-way-function) that $f: \lbrace0, 1\rbrace^{\kappa}\to \lbrace0, 1\rbrace^{\kappa}, f(x) = 1^{\kappa} $ is a one way function. Why is this the case? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The output is always the same for a particular value of k - so how would you figure out which input it came from. So it's irreversible. So it's a one-way function

Comment: @user93353: on the other hand, given $y$ such that $\exists x_0$ with $y=f(x_0)$, it's trivial to exhibit an $x_1$ with $y=f(x_1)$. So it's not collision-resistant. So… Could it be that merely stating the [definition of a OWF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#Theoretical_definition) would allow to settle the question?

Comment: @fgrieu - it fulfills the definition "A function f : {0,1}* → {0,1}* is one-way if f can be computed by a polynomial time algorithm, but any polynomial time randomized algorithm F that attempts to compute a pseudo-inverse for f succeeds with negligible probability." The definition doesn't include collision resistance. Down below, they define "A collision-free hash function f is a one-way function that is **also** collision-resistant"

Comment: @user93353 you are misunderstanding the definition of a OWF. To be a OWF it is required that finding *any* preimage is hard. This is not the case here. Outputting literally *any* $\kappa$ bit string is sufficient to break one-wayness  of a constant function. This is unsurprising given that we do not even know if one-way functions exist and their existence would imply major breakthroughs in complexity theory.

Comment: Has the answer this question refers to been deleted? The (incorrect) claim that a constant function is one-way does not appear in any of the answers I can see.

Comment: @Maeher got it now. All inputs are preimages of the constant output

Comment: @Maeher: the one deleted answer to the [linked question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24348/555) does not contain anything remotely like the incorrect claim in the present question.

Answer (score 6):

The claim (which I can't find anywhere in the answers to the linked question) is incorrect. A constant function can't be one-way. To see why, let's recall the definition of a one-way function.

A function $f : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ is one-way, if

1. There exists a polynomial time algorithm $M_f$ such that $M_f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in\{0,1\}^*$.
2. For every PPT algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ there exists a negligible function $\mathsf{negl}$ such that for all $\kappa\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds that
   $$\Pr[x\gets\{0,1\}^\kappa, y:=f(x)\;:\;f(\mathcal{A}(1^\kappa,y))=y ] \leq \mathsf{negl}(\kappa)$$

However, for any constant function is is easy to specify a PPT algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for which
$$\Pr_{x\gets\{0,1\}^\kappa}\bigl[f\bigl(\mathcal{A}(1^\kappa,f(x))\bigr)=f(x)\bigr] = 1$$
for all $\kappa\in\mathbb{N}$.
E.g., we can define $\mathcal{A}$ as the algorithm that always outputs $1^\kappa$. I.e., for all $x\in\{0,1\}^\kappa$ we have $f\bigl(\mathcal{A}(1^\kappa,f(x))\bigr) = f(1^\kappa)$ and since the function $f$ is constant, it holds for all $x\in\{0,1\}^\kappa$ that $f(1^\kappa) = f(x)$. Thus $\mathcal{A}$ breaks the one-wayness of $f$ with probability $1$ and $f$ is not one-way.

Comment: Is there an explicit reason not to say $f$ is polynomial time?

Comment: $f$ is not an algorithm, so it doesn't have a well defined runtime that could be polynomial.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought. In the linked question, there was a comment to the correct answer saying that 
"if you really must have two distinct one-way functions, you could always, say, use $1^{/2}$  instead of $0^{/2}$ for one of them.

Comment: What that comment was suggesting is using the two functions $f_1(x_1\Vert x_2) = 0^{n/2}\Vert h(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_1\Vert x_2) = 1^{n/2}\Vert h(x_1)$, just to get two *different* functions, if that were somehow required. (There are simpler solutions in that case.)